# perl command: Prepend a line of text only at the first occurrence

Tags: bash, perl

I have this input file:

```
text1
match
text2
match
text3
```

And I have this command:

```
perl -lpe 'print "prepend_me" if /^match$/' text.txt
```

And its output is:

```
text1
prepend_me
match
text2
prepend_me
match
text3
```

But I want:

```
text1
prepend_me
match
text2
match
text3
```

How do I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just count how often it got already matched and prefix it only on the first match:

```
perl -lpe 'print "prepend_me" if /^match$/ && ++$count == 1' text.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain this sintax, please?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo: I have no idea what you don't understand on this syntax because it is basic Perl. Maybe you should learn Perl first?

Comment: Thank you @Steffen. I am ashamed of my previous comment.
&& is the and of the if, while "++" or "--" means increment or decrement of 1. Since the variable count (it could be any other variable) starts from 0 by default and the increment is made in prefix notation, it means that the variable is first incremented and then the first comparison is made. This syntax makes the command very elastic and is more powerful than I thought.

Comment: I have studied that "&&" has higher precedence than "and" and have also seen some practical examples. Thank you very much @Steffen

Comment: This useful links: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321`
And this: `https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30227&seqNum=2`
have answered all my questions about this syntax.

Comment: I have also understood that the second condition is evaluated only if the first is satisfied.
So in this case the value of the variable is incremented and compared only if a match occurs.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo: fully correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with `sed`:

```
sed '0,/match/ s/\(match\)/prepend_me\n\1/' text.txt
```

- `0,/match/` is used to edit the text from the beginning (`0`) up to the first match of `match` (`/match/`).
- `s/\(match\)/prepend_me\n\1/` captures `match` (`\(match\)`) and replaces it with the desired text (`prepend_me` + linebreak (`\n`) + captured match (`\1`)).

Comment: I already know sed syntax for this but I prefer perl for some reasons. Equally an upvote for you.